# ICommand exception, thread cannot access the object

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I use this class to enable and disable a button when the network is
connected i rise an event in Gpfgateway class to notify the net is
connected and the button will be disable, when i start the app at the
begging work after i disconnect or connect the network throw an
exception. The event handler in the Gpfgateway is Thread.

Exception:

> System.InvalidoperationException in windowsBase.dll
>   Additional info: The calling thread cannot access this because a
>   different thread owns it.

refer to this line of code:

```
 CanExecuteChanged(this, new EventArgs())
```

Code:

```
public class NewAnalysisCommand : ICommand
{
    private AnalysisViewModel analysisViewModel = null;
    private Measurement measurement;


    public NewAnalysisCommand(AnalysisViewModel viewAnalysis)
    {
        analysisViewModel = viewAnalysis;
        GpfGateway.GetInstance().SystemStatus += updateCanExecuteChanged;
    }

    /// <summary>Notifies command to update CanExecute property.</summary>
    private void updateCanExecuteChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CanExecuteChanged(this, new EventArgs());
    }
    bool ICommand.CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return GpfGateway.GetInstance().IsConnected;
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;
    void ICommand.Execute(object parameter)
    { 
        NewAnalysisViewModel newAnalysisViewModel = new NewAnalysisViewModel();
        newAnalysisViewModel.NavigationResolver = analysisViewModel.NavigationResolver;

        // set CurrentPosition to -1 so that none is selected.
        analysisViewModel.Measurements.MoveCurrentToPosition(-1);
        analysisViewModel.Measurements.Refresh();
        if(((List<MeasurementViewModel>)(analysisViewModel.Measurements.SourceCollection)).Count == 0)
        {
            CanExecuteChanged(this, new EventArgs());
        }
        analysisViewModel.NavigationResolver.GoToAnalysisSettings(newAnalysisViewModel);

    }

    /// <summary>Notifies command to update CanExecute property.</summary>
    private void updateCanExecuteChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        CanExecuteChanged(this, new EventArgs());
    }
}
```

Any suggestion what can i do to use that object from that thread is very useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason of the crash is likely because the network event doesn't happen on the GUI thread.
The call to `CanExecuteChanged` goes for modification of the button that is  GUI object.
But GUI objects can only be modified on the GUI thread.

A quick fix :

```
public class NewAnalysisCommand : ICommand
{
   // ...
   private Dispatcher dispatcher;
   public NewAnalysisCommand()
   {
      // The command captures the dispatcher of the GUI Thread
      dispatcher = System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher;
   }
   private void updateCanExecuteChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
   {
      // With a little help of the disptacher, let's go back to the gui thread.
      dispatcher.Invoke( () => { 
             CanExecuteChanged(this, new EventArgs()); } 
      );
   }
}
```

Regards